# Moduli of flat connections vs Teichmuller space on surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces

The dimension of moduli of flat $SU(2)$-connection is the same as the dimension of Teichmuller space, both on a surface of genus $g$; namely both dimensions are equal to $6g-6$. Is this a coincidence or is there a way to see a correspondence?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, those spaces have the same dimension simply because $SL_2 (\mathbb{R})$ and $SU(2)$ have the same dimension.

If $M$ is a manifold and $G$ is a Lie group, then the holonomy map sends a flat $G-$connection $\nabla$ to a representation $\pi^\nabla: \pi_1 (M) \rightarrow G$. This map sends pairs of gauge equivalent connections to conjugate representations. Furthermore, one can prove that this defines a bijection between flat $G-$connections up to gauge equivalence and representations up to conjugation (I believe this is called Riemann-Hilbert correspondence).

In your case, the space of flat $SU(2)-$connections on a hyperbolic surface $S$ (modulo gauge equivalence) is identified with $Hom(\pi_1 (S), SU(2) )/G$ (the equivalence comes from identifying conjugate representations). A presentation for $\pi_1 (S)$ is given by $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_{2g} \vert \prod_{i=1}^g [a_i,a_{i+g}] \rangle$ (where $g$ is the genus of $S$), therefore $Hom(\pi_1(S), SU(2))$ has dimension $(2g).3 - 3$ because $\dim SU(2) = 3$. If you also quotient by the action of $SU(2)$ by conjugation, you get the desired $6g - 3 - 3$.

Notice that this computation only relied on the fact that $\dim SU(2) = 3$, so if you repeat the argument with $SL_2 (\mathbb{R})$, the dimension of $Hom (\pi_1 (S), SL_2 (\mathbb{R}))/G$ (the Teichmuller space of $S$ *) is also $6g-6$.

I'm no expert, so maybe there's a deeper relationship between those spaces that I'm missing.

*I should add "discrete and faithful representations" (or irreducible), but forgive my laziness.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I was not aware of was the construction of the Teichmuller space as a representation space. Do you know any reference where I can look it up?

Comment: I saw it written once in the following notes of Bergeron and Guilloux: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A5GMxHylIVZEBhpaypSCGIoCMO0Xkqol/view (sorry, it's in French).

Comment: I can just tell you the argument: start assuming that the Teichmuller space $T(S)$ is the space of metrics of curvature -1 up to being in the same conformal class. You can define a map from the space of representations to $T(S)$ as follows: take $\rho$ a representation and send it to $m_{\rho}$ the metric induced on $\mathbb{H}^2/\rho(\pi_1(S))$. One can easily check that this map is well defined on the quotient, continuous, and injective (therefore, it's open by Fenchel-Nielsen). If you check that this map is proper you're done, and this can be done using some trace inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for your time explaining this.

Comment: FWIW Teichmüller is one component if $Hom(\pi_1S,SL(2,R))/SL(2,R))$, there are more components consisting of not faithful and discrete representations.

Comment: One should add that the "naive" dimension count that you gave, proves absolutely nothing. There are numerous places where this computation is justified, you should add some references.

Comment: Sure, I was being informal. The whole explanation can be found in the following notes of Labourie https://math.unice.fr/~labourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf

Comment: @WillSawin they're closed, it's a consequence of Margulis lemma

Comment: @JoaquinLema Right, I was thinking of the noncompact case.